# How to remove specific item from local storage?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am trying to create simple comment list application, using js and local storage.
I have done all details, but at the end i want to remove specific item, which was created by application from local storage. 
I know that using `localstorage.clear()` is method which used when we want clear all data in local storage.
But what should I do when I want to remove specific item from storage, especially then data in local storage is in html format...
Here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/cjw1rf74/

```html
 <div class="created_comment">
   <div class="img_side">
   <img src="./avatar.png" style="height:40px; width:40px">
   </div>
   <div class="comment_side">
       <p>                    Enter text here...</p>
      
</div>
<span class="posit">✗</span>
</div>
```

Data inside local storage is conserved like snippet above

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): Introduce the problem, Help others reproduce the problem -> [mcve] **in the question itself**

Comment: you can remove an item using ```localStorage.removeItem('<item_key>')```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `removeItem` method available to `localStorage`

```
localStorage.removeItem('itemKey');
```

Check the reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

you can use `localStorage.removeItem('item name');` as said in [mozila reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Answer (score 0):

for Set item Into Localstorageand

```
localStorage.setItem("mytime", Date.now());
```

and For RemoveItem

```
localStorage.removeItem('mytime');
```